The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, operable program
why ng command is not working ?
I want that the command should work but it shown up an error like,
The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
I have entered the right command but this error occured.

Try installing the CLI globally.
npm i @angular/cli@latest -g

Then try accessing ng, if not an alternative is to go to the folder that contains the package.json and then run.
npx ng --version

npx will run the cli from the node_modules folder.
